# Lists, and an unknown error

Tags: list, google-apps-script

```
function testFunction() {
    var test = {
      1: 'test1',
      2: 'test2',
      3: 'test3'
    };
  Logger.log(test.1);
}
```

I'm getting the following error and I cannot figure out why. I want it to log: "test1".

Missing ) after argument list. (line 7, file "Code")

Comment: This needs a language tag (unless "List" is a language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a list, it's an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Objects in Javascript coerce their keys to strings.
What you probably want is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), like so:

```
function testFunction() {
    var test = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
    Logger.log(test[0]);
}
```

Note that arrays are 0-based, and the use of brackets.

Comment: Coercing the keys to strings has nothing to do with the error, for the record. The code won't parse properly because he is trying to access a member on a identifier, but he's using an *integer literal*. The grammar doesn't support that, for obvious reasons, thus the error message and failure to parse. However, your suggestion for using an array is good.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript (and probably most other languages), identifiers cannot start with an integer. This is because integer literals (i.e. 1, 1024, 42, etc) would not be able to be parsed. So, the following line is your problem:

```
Logger.log(test.1);
```

throws an error because you are trying to access the identifier 1 on your `test` object. Since you use an integer literal, that's what the lexer finds, and so you get that error. You need your identifiers to be strings, and strings only.